# Lagging and Flickering Animations using CSS animations

Tags: css-transitions

I am working on an interactive web UI and am running into flickering and lagging animations.

I am almost entirely using CSS transitions, adding and removing classes with jQuery to start/stop any particular animation.  I've heard this is better for performance than using jQuery animations, but I am still running into flickering and lagging animations when using Chrome (the intended browser for the application).

Check it out here:
lib.ncsu.edu/hunt_touchscreens/demo

Here is an example of one of the transitions I am doing.  It's very straightforward and I am not using any webkit, o, etc. prefixes.

```
#x {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

I hope this question isn't too open-ended, but I am curious is this just a limitation of the browser having a lot of different concurrent transitions, or are there effective strategies to avoid these performance issues.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: I don't think this is too open-ended if you give us a little bit more to go on.  can you also post your HTML and js, or provide a jsfiddle for people to try and see what you are seeing?

Comment: Unfortunately it's tough to do that since the issues only show up when the entirety of the application is loaded, and I was having trouble narrowing it down to the specific problems for a concise jsfiddle.  Pyloid had a good answer below though.  I think I'm just using way too many browser-taxing transitions.  Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's could take a lot of work, but in your site you `transition` from left/right a lot, and that taxes the browser because it has to redo it's layout as it has to calculate not only that single element moving, but any other element around it.

The trick to having performant css animations is sticking to only a couple properties that browsers are very fast at, especially when you have a transition heavy page like yours where lots of elements can potentially move at once.

Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/animations-and-performance), but the gist of it is using the following properties for changing elements,

- Position — transform: translateX(n) translateY(n) translateZ(n);
- Scale — transform: scale(n);
- Rotation — transform: rotate(ndeg);
- Opacity — opacity: n;

So you'll need to rewrite all those "left" position changes as some form of `transform: translateX();` and consider how that affects other elements within the pages if you want optimum performance.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the feedback.  I think my major advantage here is that the app is going to have a fixed screen size, so using transforms might be less difficult than for a normal responsive site.